Need Assistance Counting Characters using a Method. Need to print occurrences of a character whether input is String, Character and Character, String
I'm encountering difficulty with the prompt because my current code works correctly when the user input follows the format "character string" (e.g., "n Monday"). However, it fails to handle cases where the input format is reversed, such as "string, character" (e.g., "Today is Monday, z") or when the character and string are provided without a comma (e.g., "X, x"). The code needs to be able to handle both "character string" and "string character".
Write a program whose input is a character and a string, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the string. The output should include the input character and use the plural form, n's, if the number of times the characters appears is not exactly 1.
Ex: If the input is:
n Monday
the output is:
1 n
Ex: If the input is:
z Today is Monday
the output is:
0 z's
Ex: If the input is:
n It's a sunny day
the output is:
2 n's
Case matters. n is different than N.
Ex: If the input is:
n Nobody
the output is:
0 n's
The program must define and call the following method that takes the input string and character as parameters, and returns the number of times the input character appears in the input string.
public static int calcNumCharacters(String userString, char userChar)

This is the code I have so far:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    /* Define your method here */
    public static String calcNumCharacters(char userChar, String userString) {
        int count = 0;

        // Count occurrences of userChar
        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); ++i) {
            if (userString.charAt(i) == userChar) {
                ++count;
            }
        }

        // output
        String output = count + " " + userChar;
        if (count != 1) {
            output += "'s";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Type your code here. */
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner (System.in);

        // 
        char c = scnr.next().charAt(0);
        String userInput = scnr.nextLine();

        // condition: char and string
        String result = calcNumCharacters(c, userInput);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}

i did try to make two methods
public static String calcNumCharacters(char userChar, String userString)

and I tried
public static String calcNumCharacters(String userString, char userChar)

and in my main method i did two method calls
String result = calcNumCharacters(c, userInput);
String result2 = calcNumCharacters(userInput, c);

thinking that if the input was Today is Monday, z that it would choose the second calcNumCharacter method. This is a lazy attempt at solving my problem and I can see it doesn't work

You think what exactly is wrong with your code? (which you need to format properly in the question btw)

There is something wrong with your code - just not what you think. e.g. try it with  surprised that  does not work?. You don't actually need a Scanner btw. You could use the app arguments, e.g. int search = args[1].codePointAt(0);System.out.printf("Number of times %s appears in \"%s\" is %d%n", args[1], args[0], args[0].codePoints().filter(c ->c == search).count()); and that will give you a clue (though you needn't do it like I did)

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

One way to process the input is to read the entire line as a single String and find the character.
When you have problems, sprinkle System.out.println statements throughout your code.
The input is either:
c text
text, c

We'll make use of that comma.  We'll also make use of the String methods charAt, split, and substring.
Here's the revised run method.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Type your code here. */
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        //
        String userInput = scnr.nextLine();
        char c;
        String text;
        String[] parts = userInput.split(", ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            text = parts[0];
            c = parts[1].charAt(0);
        } else if (parts.length == 1 && !parts[0].isEmpty()) {
            int length = parts[0].length();
            c = parts[0].charAt(0);
            text = parts[0].substring(2, length); 
        } else {
            System.err.println("Nothing was input.");
            return;
        }
    
        System.out.println("" + c + " " + text);
        // condition: char and string
//      String result = calcNumCharacters(c, userInput);
//      System.out.println(result);

    }


public class LabProgram {

   void exec() {
      String text[] = getInput();
      calcNumCharacters( text );
   }

   String[] getInput() {
      Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
      String userInput = scn.nextLine();
      userInput = userInput.replaceAll( ",", "" );
      String[] parts = userInput.split( " " );
      scn.close();
      return parts;
   }

   public String calcNumCharacters( String parts[] ) {
      char cha;
      String text;
      String part[] = parts[ 0 ].split( "" );
      if( part.length == 1 ) {
         cha = parts[ 0 ].charAt( 0 );
         text = concatText( 1, parts.length, parts );
      }
      else {
         cha = parts[ parts.length - 1 ].charAt( 0 );
         text = concatText( 0, parts.length - 1, parts );
         System.out.println( text );
      }

      int count = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < text.length(); i ++ ) {
         if( text.charAt( i ) == cha ) {
            count ++;
         }
      }
      String termination = "'";
      if( count > 1 ) {
         termination = "'s";
      }
      System.out.println( "The text: '" + text + "' have " + count + " '" + cha + termination );
      return text;
   }

   String concatText( int init, int limit, String parts[] ) {
      String out = parts[ init ++ ];
      for( ; init < limit; init ++ ) {
         out += " " + parts[ init ];
      }
      return out;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      LabProgram lab = new LabProgram();
      lab.exec();
   }

}

Hello, as you will see, I took a slightly different path, let's go by parts:
First I separated the main() method from the rest, so I don't have to declare static methods unnecessarily, from there, I call exec(), which starts the execution.
We instantiate text with the return of getInput(), in this method, we take the user input, remove the comma, with replace(), create an array with split() and return it.
Then we call calcNumCharacters(), passing as argument the obtained array.
Here we create an array of String, from the first word of parts.
If the length of the array is "1", we instantiate cha with its content, and text with the string returned by concetText(), otherwise, we invert the positions, we instantiate cha with the content of the last position of the array, and text with the concatenation of the rest.
The method concatText(), receives two integers, one indicates the position from which to begin to concatenate and the other the last one to concatenate, to avoid empty spaces, we instantiate out with the content of the first valid position, and we increase "1" to init so that the for starts from there.
Then we only have to count the occurrences of the character in the string returned by concatText().

If you read my comment above, you should see why that's wrong

Hello g00se, If you are referring to the use of Scanner, I follow the OP's instructions, the ending, I already corrected it, thank you!.

If you are referring to the use of... No, I'm not ;) Did you try it on the input I suggested?

@g00se, master, if you mean entering a happy face, it seems to me that falls outside of what the statement asks for, whose input is a character and a string, not happy face.

How very old fashioned of you! These are modern characters ;)

@g00se, idol, I am an old man, and your admirer! thanks for your comments.
